# Problems building ember.js from master branch

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ember.js, rake

I'm on a macbook pro with OSX 10.7.5 installed, I've tried several times to build ember.js following the the steps on the github page, basically running "rake dist" in the cloned repository. But it does not work. Please find below my console output when I run "rake dist". Since I'm not a ruby expert I wonder if someone can point me in some direction since I don't understand the error that is preventing me to build ember.js.

```
[ alex@io ][ ~/workspace/ember.js ][ master ]
➜  rake dist --trace
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25: warning: redundant nested repeat operator
** Invoke dist (first_time)
** Execute dist
Building Ember...
rake aborted!

/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:142:in `exec_runtime'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:28:in `block in exec'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:41:in `compile_to_tempfile'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:27:in `exec'
/Users/alex/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/uglifier-2f6c31a67d6d/lib/uglifier.rb:137:in `really_compile'
/Users/alex/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/uglifier-2f6c31a67d6d/lib/uglifier.rb:74:in `compile'
/Users/alex/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/uglifier-2f6c31a67d6d/lib/uglifier.rb:47:in `compile'
/Users/alex/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-web-filters-1a6dc173776b/lib/rake-pipeline-web-filters/uglify_filter.rb:62:in `block in generate_output'
/Users/alex/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-web-filters-1a6dc173776b/lib/rake-pipeline-web-filters/uglify_filter.rb:58:in `each'
/Users/alex/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-web-filters-1a6dc173776b/lib/rake-pipeline-web-filters/uglify_filter.rb:58:in `generate_output'
/Users/alex/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-50b8d77b703c/lib/rake-pipeline/filter.rb:218:in `block (3 levels) in generate_rake_tasks'
/Users/alex/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-50b8d77b703c/lib/rake-pipeline/file_wrapper.rb:135:in `create'
/Users/alex/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-50b8d77b703c/lib/rake-pipeline/filter.rb:218:in `block (2 levels) in generate_rake_tasks'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `call'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `block in execute'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `each'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `execute'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/task.rb:166:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/alex/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-50b8d77b703c/lib/rake-pipeline/dynamic_file_task.rb:154:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/task.rb:152:in `invoke'
/Users/alex/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-50b8d77b703c/lib/rake-pipeline/dynamic_file_task.rb:60:in `invoke'
/Users/alex/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-50b8d77b703c/lib/rake-pipeline.rb:328:in `block (2 levels) in invoke'
/Users/alex/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-50b8d77b703c/lib/rake-pipeline.rb:328:in `each'
/Users/alex/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-50b8d77b703c/lib/rake-pipeline.rb:328:in `block in invoke'
:10:in `synchronize'
/Users/alex/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-50b8d77b703c/lib/rake-pipeline.rb:321:in `invoke'
/Users/alex/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-50b8d77b703c/lib/rake-pipeline/project.rb:126:in `each'
/Users/alex/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-50b8d77b703c/lib/rake-pipeline/project.rb:126:in `block in invoke'
:10:in `synchronize'
/Users/alex/.bundler/ruby/1.9.1/rake-pipeline-50b8d77b703c/lib/rake-pipeline/project.rb:112:in `invoke'
/Users/alex/workspace/ember.js/Rakefile:43:in `block in '
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `call'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `block in execute'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `each'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `execute'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/task.rb:166:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/task.rb:152:in `invoke'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rake-0.9.6/bin/rake:37:in `'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/rake:19:in `'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `'
Tasks: TOP => /Users/alex/workspace/ember.js/tmp/rake-pipeline-7aa53b2ead15d9e299f5cd1196d85943d735c070/rake-pipeline-3-tmp-7/ember-runtime.min.js
```

and here is the output when I run `bundle install` inside the root directory of the repo at the master branch

```
➜  bundle install
Using rake (0.9.6) 
Using colored (1.2) 
Using multi_json (1.3.7) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using multipart-post (1.1.5) 
Using faraday (0.8.4) 
Using hashie (1.2.0) 
Using nokogiri (1.5.5) 
Using httpauth (0.2.0) 
Using jwt (0.1.5) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using oauth2 (0.8.0) 
Using github_api (0.8.1) 
Using mime-types (1.19) 
Using rest-client (1.6.7) 
Using github_downloads (0.1.3) from https://github.com/pangratz/github_downloads.git (at master) 
Using json (1.7.6) 
Using listen (0.6.0) 
Using kicker (2.6.1) 
Using thor (0.16.0) 
Using rake-pipeline (0.8.0) from https://github.com/livingsocial/rake-pipeline.git (at master) 
Using rake-pipeline-web-filters (0.6.0) from https://github.com/wycats/rake-pipeline-web-filters.git (at master) 
Using uglifier (1.3.0) from https://github.com/lautis/uglifier.git (at master) 
Using bundler (1.2.3) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: have you tried bundle exec rake dist?

Comment: Just tried, still the same error...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have nodejs installed?
From docs ...

If you are building under Linux, you will need a JavaScript runtime for minification. You can either install nodejs or gem install therubyracer.

Assume it might be the same for Mac

Comment: Yes, nodejs is installed. I tried to build on a Ubuntu machine and it works, so I abandon the idea on building ember.js on a Mac :( I also tried to install therubyracer (although on a mac) thank you anyway. Alex

Answer (score 0):

I got it working:

```
export RUBYOPT='-E utf-8'
```

did the trick.
I'm going to close the question.